# How do I modify keys in a KeyboardProc hooking procedure?

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I can use the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to hook a custom [KeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In the hooked procedure I can return `1` to block the keyboard input from reaching the application, however what I'm trying to do is actually **modify** the data. E.g. the user hits the key `A` and I'd like to replace that with key `B`.

But any modifications I make to the `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` arguments do not seem to have any effect in the application, it will still receive the original keys. E.g. to show a little pseudocode:

```
LRESULT KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    memset(&wParam, 0, sizeof(WPARAM));
    memset(&lParam, 0, sizeof(LPARAM));

    // call the next procedure
    return CallNextHookEx(keyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

No matter what modifications I make to the two parameters it will not have an effect, once the app reads the `WM_KEYDOWN` message it will receive the original keys as they were hit.

Is there any way I can actually make modifications to the keys?

Comment: You sureley are modifying the paramse the wrong way. Take a look, which bits are relevant . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> The WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook enables you to monitor keyboard input events about to be posted in a thread input queue.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks?redirectedfrom=MSDN#wh_debug

This means it is read-only and the params can not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `SendInput`, but only when `lParam` - which should be type-cast to `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*`) - has the `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag in its `flags` field.

Here's some [D language](http://wiki.dlang.org) code copied verbatim from one of my projects:

```
extern(Windows)
LRESULT LowLevelKeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    auto kbs = cast(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

    // generate a new key event only if this key event was user-generated.
    if (!(kbs.flags & LLKHF_INJECTED))
    {
        // Alt == toggle key binding
        if (kbs.flags & LLKHF_ALTDOWN)
            useKeyMap ^= 1;

        if (!useKeyMap)
            return CallNextHookEx(keyHook_LL, code, wParam, lParam);

        INPUT input;
        input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input.ki.dwFlags = (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) ? 0 : KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        // replace the key, must be in range 1 to 254
        input.ki.wVk = keyMap.get(cast(Key)kbs.vkCode, cast(Key)kbs.vkCode);

        SendInput(1, &input, INPUT.sizeof);
        return -1;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(keyHook_LL, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```